# Are there any halachic issues with cut flowers grown in Israel?

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, agriculture, state-of-israel

Produce grown in Israel is subject to many additional agricultural laws (*shemita*, *terumah*, *maaser*, etc.). Thus occasionally there are alerts about bell peppers, etc. for sale in American supermarkets which are product of Israel and have special *halachot* regarding how they should be treated.

Occasionally I've seen cut flowers for sale, grown in Israel. Any issues we need to know about those?

Answer (score 5):

Decorative flowers do not have any Shemitta issues according to most Poskim.

If the prime importance is the fragrance they have Kedushas Sheviyis.

It is best to avoid Israeli flowers during and right after Shemitta.

http://www.ohryosef.org/shmitta/bod008.htm

Comment: "It is best to avoid Israeli flowers during and right after Shemitta." The linked source recommends avoiding Israeli flowers only if the laws of _sh'mita_ have not been followed while growing and exporting them.